# How to create a small widget to display data from remote server using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to build a platform which will allow users to add timings on the user section and then they can add few codes to display the time on their website.

So far I have completed the back section using PHP and Mysql where users can add/update timings.

Now I am stuck for the front panel.

Two things to know that this widget kind of thing will be displaying to their website so I have to setup remote connection to database on my server obviously without giving database credentials to the users.

I am new to PHP and didn't know till today that "Include" only works for the local server so I can't include my database.php which holds mysql credentials.

If you go on this website http://islamicsocietyoftoronto.com you will notice prayer time on right hand. This is actually I am trying to replicate.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You put the `URL` to your timer in an `<iframe>` that your users can put on their page.

Comment: Good idea Patrick, not ideal though. That link I sent you I have backend access for it and he has build using JAVA/Jquery and ASP. Any idea what I can do to replace it using PHP Mysql